# @IBAction: Fall Back to Default Behavior

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa, copy-paste

How to fall back to the default behavior when implementing an action?

For example I'd like to handle table row copying while preserving the default cell editing copy behavior. Or handle `doubleClick` for a table column and still be able to enter edit mode by double-clicking cells in other columns.

```
@IBAction func copy(_ sender: Any)
{
    guard view.window?.firstResponder == myTable &&
        myTable.editedRow == -1 else
    {
        // TODO: Don't break default behavior
        return
    }

    // Copy selected rows
}
```

Comment: You have to pass it along the responder chain: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH3-SW2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add an `@IBAction` in code, it appears in `Interface Builder` under the `Received Actions` of `First Responder`.

[image: First Responder]

One solution is to **connect the `Sent Action`** you want to handle **to that `Received Action`** instead of directly to your `@IBAction` in code. That way other controls get a chance to handle the event.